# Can't show array on index using handlebars on a NodeJs+Express server

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I've a problem using handlebars that I'm not able to solve, today it's the second day trying to solve it but I'm really stuck.

I'm trying to use handlebars for the first time because I wanted to make the web page I'm working on a bit more dynamic.

On my server I got a mongoDB, there is this search button where the user inputs whatever they want and they have to get user info from any user that match.

The response of that query comes like this:

```
_id: 5e2201a99162aa0344ed4261,
userName: 'Example',
email: 'example@example.io',
age: '23'
```

What I'm trying to do is get that data and show it on a div on users dom but for some reason I'm not being able to do it.

On my index.js file on the node server I got this function:

```
const printSearch = user => {
  console.log(user);
  res.render("main", {
    layout: "index",
    users: user
  });
};
```

This function is a callback function of the one that do the query and I know that on this function, user has the result of that query inside because of the `console.log(user);`.

Then on main.hbs I have the following code:

```
<div id="result">
  {{#if users}}
    {{#each users}}
      <p>{{users.userName}}</p>
      <p>{{users.email}}</p>
      <p>{{users.age}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

But for some reason that doesn't work, as I said before, this is my first time using handlebars so I imagine that there is something I'm missing but I'm not being able to figure it out.

It would be really helpful a bit of help in here, I'll be really glad.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: console.log is known for sometimes not displaying data correctly. Try in debugg mode and see if user data is there. I guess you handlebars renders and the console.log triggers.

Comment: Hi @LazarNikolic! Yeah the handlebars renders and the console.log triggers, I've tried it on debugg mode and the data is there, I don't know what's happening

Comment: From the `console.log` it appears that user is an object, am I correct? but you are treating it within your layout as an Array.

Comment: @wlh yeah you're right, I didn't noticed that. How could I treat it as an object instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the current iteration value, don't use `{{users.<property>}}`, just: `{{property}}`. If `users` is an array do:

```
{{#each users}}
      <p>{{userName}}</p>
      <p>{{email}}</p>
      <p>{{age}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Otherwise if `users` is a single object you can drop `{{#each}}`

```
<p>{{users.userName}}</p>
<p>{{users.email}}</p>
<p>{{users.age}}</p>
```